# make bzImage error while kernel compilation process

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, real-time, preempt-rt

I am on my ubuntu with Linux 5.8.0-40 Kernel. I am trying to change the kernel to 4.19 along with the RT preempt patch. These are the steps I followed.

1. Downloaded the tarball for 4.19 from [here](https://www.kernel.org/) and extracted it.
2. Downloaded the patch from [here](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/) and extracted it.
3. Applied the patch as stated in the [link](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/documentation/howto/applications/preemptrt_setup)
4. make menuconfig and enable fully preemptible option
5. make -j4
6. make bzImage

This is where I face issues

net/core/skbuff.c: In function ‘__napi_alloc_skb’:
net/core/skbuff.c:500:2: error: ‘pfmemalloc’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘pmd_alloc’?
500 |  pfmemalloc = nc->page.pfmemalloc;
|  ^~~~
|  pmd_alloc

does anybody knows how to get around this thing?  Google search solutions didn't help.

Comment: It would help if you indicated exactly which files you downloaded.

Comment: https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.19.171.tar.xz